# Code returning impossible values

Tags: c

I started working on a program generating an array, following a geometric progression with the number of elements, first element and ratio entered by the user. For some reason it's returning very... discouraging numbers.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void GenProg(float input[], int n, float first, float ratio, float *last){

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    first = input[0];
    input[i] = input[i - 1] * ratio;
    }
*last = input[n - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("Element %i is: %f. \n", i + 1, input[i]);
  }
}

int main(){
float arr[25];
float a;
int n;
printf("Number of elements: ");
scanf("%i", &n);
printf("\n");
float first;
printf("First element: ");
scanf("%f", &first);
printf("\n");
printf("Ratio: ");
float ratio;
scanf("%f", &ratio);
GenProg(arr, n, first, ratio, &a);
printf("Last element: %f.\n", a);
}
```

Thanks.

For `n = 5; first = 1; ratio = 2`
I get:

```
`Element 1: -107374176.000000`
`Element 2: -214748352.000000`
`Element 3: -429496704.000000`
`Element 4: -858991408.000000`
`Element 5: -1717986816.000000`
```

Comment: Don't make us guess -- tell us exactly what the problem is. *discouraging numbers* is not at all descriptive.

Comment: what did the debugger show you is happening?

Comment: I guess 41 or 43 are discouraging numbers since they are *not* the answer

Comment: Looks like C, not C++.

Comment: It does not look like you initialize arr. Remember local POD variables will not be set to 0. Although you should have seen this in the first minute of debugging. Learning to use your debugger is an essential skill.

Comment: *Please* correct your indentation. Trying to read other people's code is painful enough (whether it's good code or not) even *with* proper indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first = input[0];
```

Pretty sure you have that backwards. Should be

```
input[0] = first;
```

Also, there's no reason it should be in the loop body. It should go before the first for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `arr[0] = first` before calling GenProg